# Enqueue in C using linked list implementation

Tags: c, queue

I'm getting the commented errors in this function while using enqueue in the following code: I'm not able to resolve them

```
void enqueue (tweet ** head, tweet ** tail, tweet * node)
{
    tweet * p = (tweet*)malloc(sizeof(tweet));
    p->id = 10000;
    strcpy(p->text,"Hi");
    strcpy(p->user, "Me");
    p->next = NULL;

    if(isEmpty(*head))
    {
        head = tail = p;  // incompatible pointer type error here
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = p;  /*error: '*tail' is a pointer; did you mean to use '->'?, when I try to use '->' 
                           still it shows this error*/
        tail = p; // incompatible pointer type error here
    }
}
```

This is the header file which I included:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct microtweet
{
    int id;                       //non-unique integer value
    char user [51];               // the username / userid of the person who wrote the tweet
    char text [141];              // the text of the tweet
    struct microtweet *next;      //dynamic connection to the next tweet
}
tweet;
tweet *head;
tweet *tail;
void enqueue (tweet ** head, tweet ** tail, tweet * node);
int isEmpty (tweet * head);
```

Comment: _Side note:_ Rather than using _two_ double pointers, I'd create a "list" struct: `typedef struct { tweet *head; tweet *tail; } list_t;`. Then, change to: `void enqueue(list_t *list,tweet *node)` and pass around the list struct pointer to all/most of the functions (e.g. `int isEmpty(const list_t *list) { return (list->head == NULL); }`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `head` and `tail` are of type `tweet **` while `p` is of type `tweet *`. You can fix it, by changing `head` to `*head` and `tail` to `*tail`.

First fix:

```
// head = tail = p; <-- incorrect
*head = *tail = p;
```

Second fix:

```
// tail->next = p; <-- incorrect
(*tail)->next = p;
```

Third fix:

```
// tail = p; <-- incorrect
*tail = p;
```